# CentOS custom install ISO error setting up base repository

Tags: linux, iso

I tired to create my own CentOS ISO install image. I followed instructions from [here](http://www.smorgasbork.com/2014/07/16/building-a-custom-centos-7-kickstart-disc-part-1/). I copied all the packages from CentOS minimal install CD image, and didn't add any extra package. I just want's to add a kickstart to make it automatically install. However, when I tried to use this new Image to install (without kickstart for now), it shows **Error setting up base repository** and I tried to configure the installation source, the repository didn't pass verify. It says **This media is not good to install from.**

However, I tried to use the CD image which I copied data from, it passed verification and everything works fine. I believe I just copied the data from a correct CD image and made another one has exactly the same packages and configurations. But it just didn't work.

I got some information from text mode, I saw an error says:

**Error running arch: No such file or directory.**

Does anyone know what happens? Thanks a lot.